# Can not create flutter project with android studio

Tags: flutter

Could not find an option named "androidx". Run `flutter -h` (or `flutter   -h`) for available flutter commands and options.

Comment: run flutter doctor from command line to check if everything is in order

Comment: no problem when i try flutter doctor on cmd,but it doesn't even create a new project

Comment: flutter doctor only checks if installation and dependencies are correct

Comment: It seems that your Android Studio Flutter plugin is newer than your installation of Flutter. The plugin is trying to run "flutter create" and probably passing the `--androidx` command line param, but maybe you have an older version of flutter that doesn't understand that newer command line option. You can always simply create the project using "flutter create" yourself from the command line.

Comment: thanks bro it works with command line option,it costs me to much time

Answer (score 2):

Richard is correct. Upgrading flutter will resolve this issue in Android Studio.  At the command line type:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Perfect. That did it. Thanks.